# Why All the text is invisible in Intellij?

Tags: x11, java, fonts, manjaro, intellij

I have installed manjaro and intellij.

For a couple of month now I had no problems at all and I was fine with that.
Since yesterday I experience a strange bug.

The whole text is gone.

What I tried so far:

- reinstalled Intellij 13.1.3-2 community edition via pacman.
- installed pycharm to see if the problems occurs in that edition as well.

  - strangely in pycharm text appears although it is the same fonts style as the ViewContainer Header. I don't think that that is normal.

Now I think that maybe I deleted a font or something similar. (I remember a 500MB Update that ran through pacman)

Does anyone has an idea how to solve it?

Comment: try to remove the .intellij directory in your home directory and try to re install it, it's helped me while faced the same issue. If you have any project save the projects before removing .intellij Directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is [a bug](https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/40871) in new jre7:

Downgrade or add this line in the `/etc/profile.d/jre.sh` file.

```
 export _JAVA_OPTIONS='-Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=on -Dswing.aatext=true'
```